# elastic beanstalk get error 502 Bad Gateway when i trying deploy nestjs

Tags: node.js, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, nestjs-config

25

I am running a nest.js app on Amazon Elastic Beanstalk and my environment was successfully created, but when I go to my environment via the URL Amazon has created, I receive a 502 Bad Gateway nginx/1.6.2 error. I believe Elastic Beanstalk runs and it doesn't work, (error message):
Degraded
Impaired services on all instances.

Following services are not running: web.

mypackage.json config

```
{
  "name": "demo",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "",
  "author": "",
  "private": true,
  "license": "UNLICENSED",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "nest build",
    "format": "prettier --write \"src/**/*.ts\" \"test/**/*.ts\"",
    "start": "nest start",
    "start:dev": "nest start --watch",
    "start:debug": "nest start --debug --watch",
    "start:prod": "node dist/main",
    "lint": "eslint \"{src,apps,libs,test}/**/*.ts\" --fix",
    "test": "jest",
    "test:watch": "jest --watch",
    "test:cov": "jest --coverage",
    "test:debug": "node --inspect-brk -r tsconfig-paths/register -r ts-node/register node_modules/.bin/jest --runInBand",
    "test:e2e": "jest --config ./test/jest-e2e.json"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@nestjs/class-validator": "^0.13.4",
    "@nestjs/common": "^9.0.0",
    "@nestjs/core": "^9.0.0",
    "@nestjs/mongoose": "^9.2.2",
    "@nestjs/platform-express": "^9.0.0",
    "class-transformer": "^0.5.1",
    "class-validator": "^0.14.0",
    "mongoose": "^7.0.2",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.13",
    "rxjs": "^7.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@nestjs/cli": "^9.0.0",
    "@nestjs/schematics": "^9.0.0",
    "@nestjs/testing": "^9.0.0",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.13",
    "@types/jest": "29.2.4",
    "@types/node": "18.11.18",
    "@types/supertest": "^2.0.11",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.0.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.0.0",
    "eslint": "^8.0.1",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.3.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^4.0.0",
    "jest": "29.3.1",
    "prettier": "^2.3.2",
    "source-map-support": "^0.5.20",
    "supertest": "^6.1.3",
    "ts-jest": "29.0.3",
    "ts-loader": "^9.2.3",
    "ts-node": "^10.0.0",
    "tsconfig-paths": "4.1.1",
    "typescript": "^4.7.4"
  },
  "jest": {
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "js",
      "json",
      "ts"
    ],
    "rootDir": "src",
    "testRegex": ".*\\.spec\\.ts$",
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.(t|j)s$": "ts-jest"
    },
    "collectCoverageFrom": [
      "**/*.(t|j)s"
    ],
    "coverageDirectory": "../coverage",
    "testEnvironment": "node"
  }
}
```

although i trying set port env in variable is 8080 but it don' work, i think it some wrong something in my code setup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 — Create a Procfile in the root of your project and add the following content. This file will tell the Elastic Beanstalk engine to run the commands defined.

web: npm run deploy
2 — Add a "deploy" script to your package.json file

```
"scripts": {
  ...
  "deploy": "npm ci && npm run build && npm run start:prod"
  ...
}
```

3 — Make sure that your app can listent to a PORT environment variable.

```
import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';
​
async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
  await app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000);
}
bootstrap();
```

Comment: it work for me to deploy successfull